# What are the symbols on the DIY cards?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Different DIY cards have symbols on them - I just got a whole bunch that have a hammer symbol on them, for example. I am pretty sure the basket symbol means I have that object in my inventory, but I am not sure what the checkmark or the hammer symbol mean, or if there are any other symbols I just haven't seen yet.

What are these symbols? What do they indicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three common symbols on your DIY cards:

- Hammer: You have the materials to craft this DIY at a workbench
- Basket: You have one (or more) of these items in your pockets
- Checkmark: You have crafted this recipe at least once (Which is relevant for certain Nookmile achievements, I believe)

Additionally, the recipes will have backgrounds that match the general kind of materials you need to make them. For example:

- Green: Plants / weeds
- Brown: Wood
- Grey: Iron Nugget
- White: Other (e.g. bait / medicine)

Comment: There's also a paint brush, meaning the item can be customized.

Comment: White background seems to be for "other"; It's also used for the medicine recipe (no fish involved) and shell recipies. Fruit recipes have fruit colored backgrounds (at least orange recipes have orange background). Light blue looks to be for furniture ingredient recipes.

Comment: @jaxad0127 I have a few furniture recipes that are yellow (medium cardboard boxes), so I think it's more of a "general guideline" thing than the symbols.